# keyPressListener in document

Tags: gwt

There exist any method like `document.addKeyPressListener`, `DOM.addKeyPressKistener` or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is document.onKeyDown

you use that with a callback function that fires after the key is pressed. Also, you can get what key was pressed as an integer pertaining to the key.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0280__Document/documentonkeydown.htm

Comment: onKeyDown does not exist in GWT

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [`addDomHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#addDomHandler%28H,%20com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.Type%29) on the `RootPanel.get()` (which wraps the document's `<body>`) or `RootLayoutPanel.get()`, or use [`Event.addNativePreviewHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html#addNativePreviewHandler%28com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.NativePreviewHandler%29).